# Why is there an asterisk next to the error list tab?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have noticed in Visual Studio 2015 there is an asterisk next to the `Error List` tab. No other toolbar tabs have this asterisk. The asterisk is present regardless of whether the solution has errors or not. What does the asterisk signify?

[image]

Comment: There is no asterisk for the Error List tab on my machine.